# TFS 2010 build config transform problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, transform, config, tfsbuild

I'm facing quite a problem while setting up automated TFS Builds. Basically I created new configuration called *Tests*, added *transform config*, defined different connection strings for the Database. Then defined TFS build, building whole solution with MSBuild arguments `/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:Configuration=Tests`.
The problem is that in the drop location (Build_PublishedWebsites\Project) I get `web.config`, `web.debug.config`, `web.release.config` and `web.tests.config`, however I would expect just one transformed `web.config`.

I already checked PDC presentation [Web Deployment Painkillers: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 & MS Deploy](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT56) but didn't help.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your Build Template, for example .. the screenshot here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2010/04/24/package-and-publish-web-sites-with-tfs-2010-build-server.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Web.config transforms are part of the new Web Publishing Pipeline (WPP) in Visual Studio 2010.

During the build process the "CopyWebApplication" target is executed to copy the website to the _Websites folder on the build output directory. Due to backwards compatibility reasons, MSBuild uses the "old" (VS2008) copy behavior by default and not the new WPP system.

To opt-in to using WPP, set the following MSBuild properties:

```
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True
/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False
```

Comment: This was just the ticket! For clarity's sake: you have to use both of these settings or you get an error. Details here: http://aaron.stemen.me/blog/post/2010/12/29/Web-Deployment-Builds-in-TFS-2010-Part-2.aspx

Comment: awesomeness!, the easiest way to accomplish this without modifying the workflow or the project.

Comment: Thanks, this worked - I had to do this for TFS 2012 too